# Adding additional data in the DRF api endpoint

Tags: django, api, wagtail, django-rest-framework

My endpoints.py have:

```
from wagtail.api.v2.endpoints import BaseAPIEndpoint

from .models import Week, Ingredient, Menu

class WeekAPIEndpoint(BaseAPIEndpoint):
    model = Week
def register_endpoints(api_router):
    api_router.register_endpoint('week', WeekAPIEndpoint)
```

And if I follow the link **127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/week** i get this:

[image]

Is it possible to raise data by one step in DRF endpoints?
from here **127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/week/1**:

[image]

I opened [issue](https://github.com/khashashin/blemmy/issues/3) in my github. Didn't want to create too big a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Oleg [here](https://github.com/khashashin/blemmy/issues/3#issuecomment-326294026), the problem is solved by adding 1 line of code in the endpoints like there:

```
class WeekAPIEndpoint(BaseAPIEndpoint):
    model = Week
    listing_default_fields = BaseAPIEndpoint.listing_default_fields + ['year', 'week']
```

so its takes my "year" and "week" fields and picks them up, so my api endpoint looks good Thanks @oleg.

[image]